# How to draw on the entire area of a resized TImage in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, timage

I've narrowed a problem I have drawing on `TImage.Canvas` in Delphi 2009 down to the following reproducible case:

Given: a form, a `TImage`, `TLabel` and `TButton` on it. The `TImage` is anchored to all four edges so that resizing the form will resize the `TImage`. What I want to be able to do is draw on the maximal area of `Image1` available to me after resizing. So in my test case I have the following code in my the Button's `OnClick` handler:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption:= IntToStr (Image1.Width)+' x '+IntToStr(Image1.Height);
  Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color:= 0;
  Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(0,0,Image1.Width, Image1.Height);
end;
```

You'll see that if the form is resized, `Image1.Width` and `.Height` change as expected, however the rectangle that is drawn if the resized form is *larger* than the original one, will be incomplete, only drawing on the same area that was there previously.

**How do I get it do use the entire resized area?**

For what it's worth, in my original problem I had played with `Image1.Stretch`, which allows me to use more of the area upon resizing but will result in my drawings being distorted (not desired). If I also use `Image1.Proportional`, then it's better but I still can't use the full area available. `Image1.AutoSize` doesn't seem to be doing anything useful to me either.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you want something you can paint on, TImage is the wrong choice. TImage is for displaying graphics. If you want it to look different, change the underlying graphic and then just refresh the image. If you want to paint directly onto a control, use a TPaintBox instead.

Comment: @Rob - thanks for pointing this out. I actually do both, painting and displaying, and TImage was the more convenient choice in this specific case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an OnResize-event to your form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Width := Image1.Width;
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Height := Image1.Height;
end;
```

Also, if you are using the component to draw on, rather than displaying images from file etc, consider using the TPaintBox rather than TImage.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Re. the TPaintBox  suggestion - in the real app, I have to do several other things with it beside drawing on, so TImage suits me better.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have to also adjust Image1.Picture.Width/Height or Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Width/Height.